# Add entry into firebase without authentication

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am coding an application for the main purpose of spreading awareness of vulnerabilities. Originally, there is no need for users to submit information hence I've set the write as false. Hence, signups and authentication were not necessary.

However, now my application has a function where users can check if their device is vulnerable and the outcome of the result which are device information and vulnerability status will be uploaded to the database such as the following:

[image]

Is there any rules or methods to protect this branch from malicious users uploading/updating/deleting the entire branch without login authentication?

Currently, my rules are the following:

[image]

Comment: Going forward please don't post screenshots of textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. For the database, you can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not granting write permission on `/User_Entry` it is already impossible for folks to delete the entire branch with a single API call.

What *is* possible is for them to read the entire `/User_Entry` branch, and then delete the child nodes one by one. If you don't want to allow that, consider removing that root-level `".read": true` and instead granting read permission only to the exact path that your code reads.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Phone_Model": {
      ".read" true
    }
    "Poc_Demo": {
      ".read" true
    }
  }
}
```

**The basic premise is thart your rules should allow only exactly what your code does, and nothing more.**

So for example, if your code only ever adds new child nodes to `/User_Entry`, but never deletes any of them, then you shouldn't give full `".write": true` permission, but instead limit them to creating new nodes only:

```
".write": "!data.exists()"
```

Comment: thank you for the response! I appreciate that it does solve the issue of not allowing threat actors from deleting the entire branch. However, the threat actor can still in theory create tons of new nodes and fill up the branch. Is the only way to mitigate this via user authentication and set a max entry child size for each user id?